# Set list of applications allowed for execution by unprivileged user

Tags: executable, access-control

I am working on a project of security enforced Linux-based system (kernel 2.6.32 + Gnome 2 + Centos package base mostly). We need to implement the restriction of execution of unallowed executables.

Source compiling, package building, scripting and `chmod +x` command will be prohibited in this system. Briefly speaking we need to **restrict any execution by default** for a unprivileged (non root) user excepting the very short list of user-space application (X.org, office, browser etc). I guess that it's not enough to use discretionary access control in this case, rather it should be a kind of a mandatory access control superstructure.

What is a preferable way to work it out? I heard something about SELinux and ACL rules but I'm not shure.Thank you.